# Extrude Between Tool not working for me

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, tin

I am having an issue with trying to use the extrude between tool in ArcScene. I had 8-9 geologic formations that I would like to create a 3d polygon of these formations. My workflow process went something like this:

Took top elevations of each geologic formation -> Natural Neighbor -> Raster to TIN -> and I believe I should be using the extrude between tool here. I cannot find any reference material to see exactly how the tool should work so I am turning here. I have been following this workflow explained in the thread to go by (http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/6973-Creating-Cross-Sections-in-ArcScene)

I also found this thread showing other people maybe having the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8883-No-output-quot-Extrude-Between-quot-two-TIN-surfaces-generated-from-two-3D-polygons?p=297214#post297214)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I should of done some more digging on the tool. The input polygon is your horizontal constraint of the area to where your tin's would be your vertical constraint. I got everything to come in fine now.